# Merge is taking long time to update records

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g

[image]We are using a merge query to UPDATE 2 columns from a source table that has the same structure as the target table. But when executed the merge query keeps running for a very long time. The source table PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356 has "22603114" rows and the target table "EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP" to which update must be done consists of "1118892748" rows. The target table has an index on these columns.

```
MERGE INTO EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP A USING
EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356 B ON
(
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE ;
```

These are the Index defined in the target table "PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP"

**PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_60  HR_PAY_PERIOD_KEY
PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_64    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_61    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY
PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_02    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY
PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_03    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY**

Comment: did you run an explain plan and look at the results?  That is the 1st thing to do. If you are using sqldeveloper, it is the button next to the execute on the toolbar.  Run that and post your results.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I have attached the explain plan as per your request , can you please help me on the above

Comment: Yeah you are still doing full table scans on millions of rows.  Not good.  So is that just one index you have?  Can you please edit the question and include the index definition?  You probably need indexes on both tables.  Adding a new index will take some time though.

Comment: @OldProgrammer is there a way we can use parallel hints or force index using hints to make the process faster?

Comment: You need a better index on both tables, probably ones that include multiple columns. Trying to force the use of an existing index, when the optimiser has already decided that none of the existing indexes are helpful, is unlikely to see a significant performance improvenent

Comment: @NickW should I create the same set of indexes on the same column's in the other table since both tables have the same structure and columns in them? And does the performance of merge increase if the no of condition used in on clause are reduced?

Comment: If the requirement is to merge two tables of 22M rows and a billion rows with no filtering conditions then it is inevitably going to take some time. Maybe indexing the join keys of the billion row table might help a little. Parallel should help (alter session enable parallel DML and hint with `merge /*+ parallel */` - from 12.1 you can hint `enable_parallel_dml` in place of the alter session).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson is it possible to use filter condition in the merge, cause I have to update the 2 columns if the A.SRC_CREATED_DATE  <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE AND 
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE

Comment: @karthik yes you can, by adding a `where` clause to the `update`. However it still needs to join 22M rows to 1000M rows, if that's the requirement.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson We are doing this as sn one-time update, is there any alternative method for this, the target table is not partitioned. Will using merge /*+ parallel */ work if the target table is not partitioned?. Is it required to just give parallel hint as above or specify the degree of parallelism like  /*+ PARALLEL(8) */. We use oracle 12C 2.2 version

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I get the following error when using parallel hints. MERGE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P02T
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables